# MySQL Group By Count Substring

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a script to identify which email providers in our database are the most popular. URL links is the name of the table and 'contact_email' is the contact email address associated with the link.

I wrote the following MySQL query

```
SELECT
url_links.contact_email,count(url_links.contact_email)
FROM
url_links
group by contact_email order by count(url_links.contact_email) DESC
```

This query returns all of the emails and the count of the person who submitted the listing. What I'd like to do is modify the MySQL script so that it gives me a count of the whole provider. i.e.  Gmail.com, Yahoo.com, Hotmail.com etc.

I could read this entire array into PHP and do an 'explode' on the @ sign and group it that way, however I'm curious if the community knows how to modify this script so that instead of the count being each email address - it gives back a count of ALL email addresses in Gmail, Yahoo etc. in the group by

Aka a 'Group By Substring' where all the items would be grouped by everything after the '@'sign.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can group and count by:

```
right(url_links.contact_email, length(url_links.contact_email)-INSTR(url_links.contact_email, '@'))
```

something like this should work:

```
SELECT
right(url_links.contact_email, length(url_links.contact_email)-INSTR(url_links.contact_email, '@')), count(right(url_links.contact_email, length(url_links.contact_email)-INSTR(url_links.contact_email, '@')))
FROM
url_links
group by right(url_links.contact_email, length(url_links.contact_email)-INSTR(url_links.contact_email, '@')) order by count(right(url_links.contact_email, length(url_links.contact_email)-INSTR(url_links.contact_email, '@'))) DESC
```

Comment: Thanks Cesar. I tried your script, however it returned the same output as my script. One result per email instead of one result per provider.

Comment: Hi Viktor, I updated my answer, i was grouping (and selecting) by the wrong "url_links.contact_email" field

Comment: That worked! Can I ask you a bonus question?  How would you add an additional MySQL field that is called 'percentage' - i.e. it takes the full count of the entire database and expresses it as a percentage of the 'list' under a given provider?

Comment: Hi, is good to know that it works, please, ask it as a new question, there not should be two questions in the same tree, and, please, if the answer solves the problem, please mark it

Comment: I marked - it as solved. Thank you again.  Here is my next question: [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39578487/mysql-update-if-a-subtring-exists-in-another-table). I've put the output of that query in a separate table that we've modified to remove the good links.