# MYSQL Update IF a subtring exists in another table Inner Join

Tags: mysql, inner-join, email

What I'm working on is an email clean up script for our database.  In so doing we identified a list of domains that are invalid, broken or no longer around. We do this by identifying the domain name i.e. everything after the @ sign.

```
update url_links
set link_bad=1,
    emailCarrier='bad-domain.com'
where contact_email like '%@bad-domain.com';
```

identifies the provider and sets the field. The problem is we have hundreds of domains that are not valid (the above is just an example)

What I'd like to do is 'inner join' to another table that is called 'emailCarriers.  I could write this as a loop in PHP but I wanted to ask the community here if someone had a clever way to do this in MySQL.

The emailCarriers table contains all the bad domain carriers so the query would reference the emailCarriers table and seek to find a match on the substring of the domain name portion (after the @ sign) and if its a match then it would perform the update and fill in the 'bad-domain.com' with the corresponding domain from the emailCarriers table.

Thanks!

Comment: `update` allows `join`s.

Comment: Yes I am aware that update allows joins however I'm still a beginner when it comes to understanding the syntax of the join to the other table emailCarriers.  That table has a field called 'provider' .  As long as there's a match with the provider being the same carrier as any record in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update url_links ul
join emailCarriers ec on ul.contact_email like concat('%@', ec.domain)
set ul.link_bad=1,
    ul.emailCarrier=ec.domain;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

ul.emailCarrier = 'bad-domain.com' should actually fetch the domain from the other table - that's where my challenge is - your script sets all the results to 'bad-domain.com' - if its a match for 'email.ru' or any of a hundred different bad domains I'd like that stored in the field. how do I identify the matching result?   So if I understand correctly if you follow an update with an abbreviation you can refer to it in shorthand.

Comment: @Viktor `ul` is an alias for `url_links`. If you want to set `emailCarrier` to the same domain, just do `ul.emailCarrier = ec.domain`.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:-

```
UPDATE url_links u JOIN emailCarrier e 
ON u.SUBSTRING_INDEX(url_links, '@', 1) = b.provider
SET link_bad = 1
```

Comment: Thanks Ankit - how would you get the substring and assign it to the emailCarrier variable field as in my example above?  There are two SET's - 1 is the link_bad and the other is the carrier itself. The carrier field is the result of the substring.